How to connect multiple texture coordinate with a different object in 1 vector?
I want to learn how to connect all texture coordinates with a different object into 1 vector? is there a way to connect it and make it work without messing the effect of the nodes? thank you in advance for answering :)


It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Can you describe the end result you'd like? Can you explain what "without messing the effect of the nodes" means?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Phrogz I already fixed, thanks for your answer

Would you like to post your solution as an answer, to gain reputation on this site and (more importantly) perhaps help future people with similar questions?
